# gRPC Python: Unexpected keyword argument 'syntax'

Tags: python, protocol-buffers

When using `protoc`-generated `_pb2.py` files after changing things that are installed on my machine (testing a clean-install procedure), I get the following error:

```
File "client.py", line 16, in <module>
  from google.protobuf.field_mask_pb2 import FieldMask
File "/usr/local/my-python-local/lib/python/site-packages/google/protobuf/field_mask_pb2.py", line 22, in <module>
  serialized_pb=_b('\n google/protobuf/field_mask.proto\x12\x0fgoogle.protobuf\"\x1a\n\tFieldMask\x12\r\n\x05paths\x18\x01 \x03(\tBQ\n\x13\x63om.google.protobufB\x0e\x46ieldMaskProtoP\x01\xa0\x01\x01\xa2\x02\x03GPB\xaa\x02\x1eGoogle.Protobuf.WellKnownTypesb\x06proto3')

TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'syntax'
```

What gives??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem was due to an outdated/conflicting install of `protobuf`: this "unexpected keyword argument" error is associated with an older version of `protobuf` --- 2.6.2 I believe.

To solve this, just reinstall protobuf:

```
pip uninstall protobuf
pip install protobuf==3.0.0b2
```